# Deleting Autocomplete Textview Data

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a Autocomplete TextView...
What I want to do is that when a button e.g. like 'Clear' is pressed, the Data of the Autocomplete Textview should be erased so that whenever someone types something, there are no suggestions...
How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to do it
1. Clear the text on onFocusChange
2. Clear the text on onClickListener on "Clear" button

```
// implementation of OnClickListener
yourButton.OnClickListener clearListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do something when the button is clicked 
        yourAutocompletetextview.setText("");
    }
};
```

Comment: Will the Suggestions appear again as they should untill the button is pressed the next time?

Comment: Yes it will. Definitely the suggestions will appear again.

Answer (score 1):

just set the text of autocomplete TextView by

```
textview.setText("");
```

in your button's onclick

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend setting the TextView to empty (e.g. `.setText("")`) and then setting the AutoComplete Adapter to null/empty in the onClick event for the 'Clear' button.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask to not show the suggestions, you could set the DropDownHeight to 0 with 
    AutocompleteTextView.setDropDownHeight(0);

or maybe take a look at 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html